# Stop refresh on dynamically loading html contents on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page, in which I'm dynamically loading contents on Button Click using javascript. This loads my entire page as a result previous form entries gets lost.
How to avoid this?
How to retain values and stop refreshing?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to return false in the javascript function handler. You might want to look into event.preventDefault as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is my code:


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    var counter=0;
    function addMore()
    {
        ++counter;
        var string = '<div><table border="1"><tr><td><label>Name</label><input type="text" name="txtName'+counter+'"/></td></tr><tr><td><label>Age</label><input type="text" name="txtAge'+counter+'"/></td></tr></table></div>';
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML+=string;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="display.php" method="post">
    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Name</label><input type="text" id="txtName0" name="txtName0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Age</label><input type="text" id="txtAge0" name="txtAge0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:addMore()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="display" />`enter code here`
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```